# SD card reader seems not to be detected in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mount, sd-card

On an ASUS BU201 Ultrabook Ubuntu doesn't seem to recognize SD card reader. I've tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/790308/897783) but nothing will be mounted when I insert my SD card. On another Windows machine the card reads fine, so it can be assumed the card has no errors.

`ls /dev/ | grep sd` of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/826696/897783) gives me

```
sda 
sda1 
sda2 
sda3 
sda6
sda7
```

`lspci` gives me (with inserted card):

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-V (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Thermal (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro AU6601 PCI-E Flash card reader controller
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
```

which relates to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1116264/897783), but the answer didn't help me either.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

`sudo lsblk` with card (128GB) in reader gives

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/57
loop1    7:1    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/86
loop2    7:2    0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop3    7:3    0  89.4M  1 loop /snap/core/6818
loop4    7:4    0 456.4M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform/122
loop5    7:5    0 216.4M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-runtime/6
loop6    7:6    0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/258
loop7    7:7    0  34.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
loop8    7:8    0 456.4M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform/125
loop9    7:9    0 456.4M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform/128
loop10   7:10   0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/81
loop11   7:11   0  34.6M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop12   7:12   0   151M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/51
loop13   7:13   0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/61
loop14   7:14   0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/352
loop15   7:15   0   3.9M  1 loop /snap/notepad-plus-plus/207
loop16   7:16   0  35.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
loop17   7:17   0  53.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/782
loop18   7:18   0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/83
loop19   7:19   0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/406
loop20   7:20   0  88.4M  1 loop /snap/core/6964
loop21   7:21   0    74M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-3-stable/6
loop22   7:22   0  53.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/941
loop23   7:23   0   111M  1 loop /snap/zotero-standalone/36
loop24   7:24   0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/280
loop25   7:25   0   3.9M  1 loop /snap/notepad-plus-plus/205
loop26   7:26   0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
loop27   7:27   0  53.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/970
loop28   7:28   0  89.3M  1 loop /snap/core/6673
loop29   7:29   0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop30   7:30   0   151M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/40
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0  39.1G  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0 162.8G  0 part
├─sda6   8:6    0     1M  0 part
└─sda7   8:7    0  36.5G  0 part /
```

Comment: I had this problem myself, and solved it buy getting a USB SD card reader.

Comment: @CharlesGreen You seem to rob me of all illusions:)

Comment: run `sudo lsblk` with a SD card in the reader.

Comment: @vidarlo see update

Comment: But then again, I have a slightly older computer. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should try installing exFat worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Comment: Wow... That was it..

Comment: It worked. I dont know how and what this does. I had sandisk card and It was not recognized by Kubuntu when inserted in my probook 450 G4 media card. After this command I removed and re inserted and woh It get mounted automatically

Comment: Note that exfat-utils has been replaced by exfatprogs:
https://sven.stormbind.net/blog/posts/deb_debian_and_exfat/

Comment: For RHEL you might need to enable [epel-release](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-an-exfat-drive-on-centos-7/) and to `yum install exfatprogs` too.

Answer (score 1):

I have MSI GE63VR 7RF and Kubuntu 18.04. I just wanted to share my solution.

You have 3 chances to solve sd card problem
First Method : (my problem solution)
fix kernel modules to load your driver at boot time.

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

### add below line end of the file

```
tifm_sd
```

### save and exit

### reboot

```
sudo reboot now
```

### solved !

## Second Method :

### Reset and rework sdcard modules on kernel

```
sudo modprobe -r r852

sudo modprobe -r sdhci_pci

sudo modprobe r852

sudo modprobe sdhci_pci
```

## Third Method :

### Reinstall Udisk packages !

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall udisks2
```

### reboot your system

```
  sudo reboot now
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! First solved my problem on MacBookAir7,2 with Ubuntu 23.10 (mantic) B-) I had to add facetimehd to /etc/modules, same problem (nearly) same fix!